# Debugging MacBook Pro kernel panic few minutes after resuming from standby

Tags: kernel-panic

Few months ago my MBP (Early2011) started to give a kernel panics after resuming from standby.

- This doesn't happen instantly, usually 1-10 minutes after resuming
- kernel panics do not follow a clear pattern
- I reinstalled the entire OS X 10.8.2
- reset SMC and NVRAM
- did run memtest
- did run AHT

Hardware: Intel SSD 330 & HDD (removed the DVD),8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3, AMD Radeon HD 6750M 1024 MB.

Here are the last few panics: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uw325nsr3zfbw2v/_YYGyT50mg

What else it could be? At apple store they told me that they cannot service it without putting the DVD back as this is an usupported configuration. Also the MBP is out of warranty.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of this line:

> panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff802947d5dd): "VM_PAGE_QUEUES_REMOVE: unmarked page on Q"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2050.18.24/osfmk/vm/vm_pageout.c:1924

And there's the word `page` all over the panic log, I suspect it's about your virtual memory.

Try disabling it for a few days and see if it happens again. You can find how to disable it [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=201106020948369). You can disable it, delete those VM files, and then reenable it again. It might also be caused by corrupted VM images.

Also, it could be sleep-related, or about secure virtual memory.

You can check about secure virtual memory in `System Profiler`, under Software.

Try to rule out any possibilities. You can find guide to disable sleep [here](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57510880-263/how-to-prevent-sleep-in-os-x/).

Well, disabling sleep is strongly discouraged, and I don't really think it's about secure VM, also, check your boot drive's format is Journaled HFS+.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will try these and be back with the outcomes. BTW, the volume is HFS+ with case sensitive.

Comment: @SorinSbarnea Is Journalling enabled?

Comment: Yes, and also I did a repair after each kernel panic.

Comment: Another possibility, is the inconsistency between your wake and  sleep. Check if the status of your hardware has been modified.

Comment: Have you ruled out other possibilities yet?